# Bootstrap col leaving a space between another col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Bootstrap]

Here you can see that in-between the two col-md-6 divs, there is a little white space. I need this to b removed so that the grey bar looks like it is one.

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 performers-table" style="padding:0 !important;">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0 !important;">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rating - Top 3 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>{{$performers['over'][0]['name'] }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$performers['over'][0]['review_count_approved'] }}<div class="average-review-stars smaller-stars" id="performersover{{ $performers['over'][0]['id'] }}"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0 !important;">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rating - Top 3 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>{{$performers['over'][0]['name'] }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$performers['over'][0]['review_count_approved'] }}<div class="average-review-stars smaller-stars" id="performersover{{ $performers['over'][0]['id'] }}"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? i have removed any padding from the divs

Comment: u could give a try to: table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

Comment: Post a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the code. I don't see what you get here: http://www.bootply.com/7kXb8Re7Jv

Comment: its not happening on jsfiddle or on bootply.

Comment: there you go if its not happening in fiddle then its an issue with other css you have added

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.no-gutter** bootstrap class to avoid space between two columns.

By default a bootstrap row will contain 15px of left and right margins.